# Recursion Addition differences

Tags: java, recursion, syntax, addition

I was messing around with a recursion question (in Java) and noticed that passing in the following statements results in 3 different answers, so it'd be nice if someone told me what the differences are

Here's the function I was trying to recurse

```
    if(root.left != null){
        getVal(root.left, level + 1);
    }
```

and If were to switch it to

```
    if(root.left != null){
        getVal(root.left, level++);
    }
```

or

```
    if(root.left != null){
        getVal(root.left, level+=1);
    }
```

or

```
if(root.left != null){
    getVal(root.left, level=+1);
}
```

I'd all get different answers.
I know about the last 2, how one passes the original before adding the 1 and one adds to the value and then passes it through, but not sure how the first one differs than the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `level + 1` does not change the value of `level` and just passes the value of `level` plus 1
- `level++` passes the **original** value of `level` and then increments the value of `level` by 1
- `level+=1` increments the value of `level` by 1 and then passes this **new** value
- `level=+1` is equivalent to `level= +1` where `+` is the [unary `+` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), so it sets `level` equal to 1 and passes this **new** value

UPDATE:
The first and third versions pass the same value to the recursive call, but may behave differently depending on whether or not the variable `level` is used afterward.

Comment: First and third items may act differently if `level` value is used further.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me how 1st and 3rd case could potentially be different? Because in my case, I actually do get different results

Comment: @JustinLi 
The 1st one doesn't modify the value of the variable `level`, so if you continue to use `level` after you call `getVal(root.left, level + 1)`, its value will be the **same** as before the call to `getVal`.
The 3rd does modify the value of `level`, so its value will be **different** after the call to `getVal`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just perform a simple test to see what is going on:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int a=3, b=3, c=3, d=3;
    method(a+1);       //3+1, 4 was passed into the method
    method(b++);       //post increment, 3 was passed into the method, then increase b by 1
    method(c+=1);      //add 1 to c(3), 4 was passed into the method
    method(d=+1);      //d set to 1, 1 was passed into the method

    System.out.println("(Values in main) a:" + a + " b:" + b + " c:" + c + " d:" + d);
}

public static void method(int v){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
3
4
1
(Values in main) a:3 b:4 c:4 d:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(root.left != null){
    getVal(root.left, level + 1);
}
```

Here you pass `level+1` to `getVal()` as argument, but you don't modify `level` itself.

```
if(root.left != null){
    getVal(root.left, level++);
}
```

Here you pass `level` to the method as argument **before** it is increased (so it is passed verbatim), **but** you also modify `level` value itself (after the method call).

```
if(root.left != null){
    getVal(root.left, level+=1);
}
```

Here you pass `level+1` to the method, **and** also you change `level` itself (before the call).

```
if(root.left != null){
    getVal(root.left, level=+1);
}
```

Here you just assign `1` to `level` and call your method with `1` as an argument.

In all 4 cases you actually do something different, hence the different results.